# .htaccess redirect non www to www and http:// to https://

Tags: php

home page www.drarashmisharma.com and drrashmisharma.com redirecting to https://www.drrashmisharma.com

but internal pages are nor redirecting properly 
http://drrashmisharma.com/how-to-prepare-yourself-for-ivf.php

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.drrashmisharma.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because your second rule is not matching, you are missing a `*`.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.drrashmisharma.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: `code`
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.drrashmisharma.com/$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.drrashmisharma.com/$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^drrashmisharma\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.drrashmisharma\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/www\.drrashmisharma\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]

Comment: @Vijaysharma That's a completely different set of `RewriteRule`s. I'm guessing you are getting a redirect loop with those ?